# Config files for xterm

Tags: linux, xterm

Is there any config files for xterm for default settings? For example, on my system, xterm start with black text on white background, and I want it the other way around. I can do it by starting it with:

```
xterm -bg black -fg white.
```

I want to set in a config file that if I run it without arguments, it will start with these options.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add these lines to a file named `.Xdefaults` in your home directory.

```
xterm*background:   black
xterm*foreground:   white
```

Then, run `xrdb .Xdefaults` and launch xterm :)

And here's a full guide to .Xdefaults if you want more: http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xdefaults

Comment: and: read 'man xterm' to find out possible settings for the `.Xdefaults` file

Comment: `~/.Xdefaults` is deprecated, and `~/.Xresources` should be used instead.  See <https://superuser.com/q/243914/658727>

Answer (score 2):

Just adding an updated answer:

```
Atlas:~$ cat .Xresources
XTerm*background:   black
XTerm*foreground:   white
```

Things to note: Attributes in the file are case sensitive. Xresources has replaced Xdefaults.

Also if your xterm window (and other terminals) are slow - because the window takes several seconds to redraw the text - this can be extremely distracting, and seems to occur on some systems like the AMD Ryzen systems for some reason when switching workspaces, then add:

```
XTerm*renderFont: true
XTerm*faceName: VeraMono
XTerm*faceSize: 10
```

And forcing the system to render the fonts will fix the slow redraw / re-rendering of xterm windows contents, which can be extremely distracting when switching workspaces.

To apply:

```
xrdb .Xresources
```

All future xterminals you open will now work as they should.