# Load .Xdefaults for VcXsrv (open Xming alternative)

Tags: xterm, x-windows

I would like to run xterm with my Xresources.

I have the `.Xresources` file in the user folder to which I connect through `VcXsrv` and also in my local PC, inside `program files/vcxsrv` (both `.Xdefaults` and `.Xresources` with the same xterm formating definitions). I can't find the way to make `VcXsrv` to load this `Xdefaults` file that comes with the installation.

If I do `xrdb -merge` or `xrdb -load` inside the xterm, the next xterm that I start will be with the `Xresources` loaded. However I don't want to start with that default white background xterm and have it always in the back, but with the one for which I've put down the configuration in its folder and in my opinion should be loaded already.

Am I doing something wrong? Any ideas on how to load `Xdefaults` for the local `Xserver`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`.Xdefaults`** are read by xapps (`xterm`, `xclock`, etc.) every time xapp starts. **`.Xresources`** are usually loaded once by `xrdb` during X server startup (i.e. `startx` script). More detailed description [here](https://superuser.com/questions/243914/xresources-or-xdefaults)

When you start `xterm` at a remote machine, it tries to read remote `.Xdefaults` file. Just put your resources there or link `ln -s .Xresources .Xdefaults` in your home dir.