# How to control the font used by Athena-gvim in dialogs?

Tags: fonts, xorg, gvim, localization

To reduce the number of dependencies, I build gvim to use the Athena widgets only (no GTk, etc.) This works fine, but there is a problem with localization... My locale is set to use `KOI8-U`.

After setting the `guifont` in `~/.gvimrc`, I get the proper Cyrillics shown both in menu-titles and inside the editor -- this works:

```
set guifont=-monacocyrillic-fixed-medium-r-normal--10-100-75-75-c-60-koi8-u
```

However, the popup-windows still use some other font, which has ISO8859-1(5) characters instead of KOI8-U:

[image]

Is the setting controllable through some other gvim-variable (like `guifont`)? If not, what is the name of the X11 "resource" I should be setting? Thanks!

(BTW, how come there are no tags for "Athena" and "x11-resources"?)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the vim-developers [denied](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1766), that `guifont` should have any effect on the font used by some aspects of the Graphical User Interface, but not the others. I do not quite understand, where the line is drawn and why, but it is, what it is.

As for the X11-resources, turns out, they really *are* [documented](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/gui_x11.html). My `~/.Xdefaults` now has:

```
Vim*font: -*-serene-*-r-*-*-*-180-*-*-*-*-koi8-o
```

and the Vim's popup-windows use the font.

(Hint: you do not need to restart after editing the Xdefaults-file -- just rerunning `xrdb < ~/.Xdefaults` is usually sufficient.)

Comment: Your answer is correct, but as of today [it is more common to name that file `.Xresources`](https://superuser.com/q/243914). Why no tags for Athena? Because few people more than you and I still appreciate it :)